# Where exactly do you place arrays in your code?

Tags: java, arrays

This question is probably rather simple and routine for most of you, but I've only been doing Java for a few weeks now and we only just got to arrays in class and I usually learn best when shown specific examples.

I understand their concept and what they do, I'm just not sure where to place one in my code. I'll put one of my classes under this to give visualization to my question.

Disregard most of it as it has a few other classes it works with for what I'm doing. My question is do you declare it where I put the '--X--' with the instance variables or somewhere farther down?

I hope what I'm asking makes sense, I can try to be more specific if you need it.

```
public class library
{
   private painting art;
   private String name;
   --X--
   public library(String libName, String pTitle, int pYear, String pAuthor, String pStyle)
   {
      art = new painting(pTitle, pYear, pAuthor, pStyle);
      name = libName;
   }
   public void display()
   {
      System.out.println("Title: " +art.get_title());
      System.out.println("Author: " +art.get_author());
      System.out.println("Year: " +art.get_year());
      System.out.println("Style of painitng: " +art.get_style());
      System.out.println("Library: " +name);
   }
   public void setArt(painting a)
   {
      art = a;
   }
}
```

Comment: If it's an instance variable, then I'd put it with an instance variable, sure. Maybe the best thing would be to give [CodeReview.SE] a working program, and they can tell you where you can improve?

Comment: The decision of where to "place" (declare) an array is no different from the decision of where to place any other variable.  It depends on what you want to use the variable for, not on the type of the variable, whether array, primitive type or object.

Comment: Also, you're drawing a distinction between an array and an instance variable which doesn't exist.  An array can be an instance variable.  An array can be a local variable.  An array can be a method parameter.  An array can be a static variable.

Comment: Thank you David, that is what I was looking for. Also, yes i know that instance variables and arrays don't really have a distinction. I was just using the instance variable as a location of reference. Thank you to everyone else who commented and gave me tips/information, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the fields of your class typically go together in one block; right in the beginning of your class; no matter what specific type they have.

But that is pure convention; and technically you could place them all over the place.

But while talking about conventions: class names go UpperCase always.

So the real answer here: there coding style guides for java - simply read and stick to them.

Comment: So if my array was going to be `double[] books;` would I put it where I placed the --X--?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or maybe before the other two fields. Depending on their relationship to each other.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help! This, along with David's comment from above is exactly what I needed. I sometimes get lost in all of the technical definitions and descriptions, you both put it very simply and easy to understand. That is the stuff that helps me the most. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I order things in this priority:

1. First, the static keyword;
2. Next by the access level,
3. By taste:

   1. If there are any identifiers of the same staticity and access level, sort by verbosity of initialization, if they don't have anything to do with eachother.
   2. If identifiers are related to eachother, group them together (but put the longer ones after the shorter ones.)

So in each group, the longer initializations happen last. This way, they don't break up the grouping as much.

If you end up having a lot of groups of related identifiers, it probably means you can make separate classes.

```
public class OrderedFields {
    // public static first
    public static final String CONSTANT = "foo";

    // private static next
    private static final String PRIVATE = "bar";

    // another private static but it is longer so goes last
    private static final ImmutableList<String> NAMES = ImmutableList.of(
        "Tony P",
        "Susie Q"
        "Rodrigo"
    );

    // non-static public fields (rarely used)

    // non-static private fields
    private numberOfPeopleWhoResponded;

    // constructors are first method group
    public OrderedFields() {
        numberOfPeopleWhoResponded = addUpPeopleByNames(NAMES);
    }

    // public method
    public getNumberOfPeopleWhoResponded() {
        return numberOfPeopleWhoResponded;
    }

    // private method
    private int addUpPeopleByNames(final List<String> names) {
        int number = 0;
        names.forEach(name -> number++);

        return number;
    }

    // Inner classes and interfaces
    public static class Builder {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the above, the `ImmutableList` is a fancy version of an array.

Arrays in my opinion are best used as a constant class variable (e.g. target `private static final` first unless you have good reason not to use that.)

If you're going to be changing the contents of the array, it's probably better to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I would never group by length but by context/meaning. If A needs B, then B comes first, no matter the potential length of the init statement.

Comment: @GhostCat ah yes thats true; I'll add this above. I guess I do more of a hybrid of what context and length. At this level, it is mostly about maximizing readability and is kind of an art.

Answer (score 0):

I would restate / expand on GhostCat's answer as follows:

- Your aim should be to maximize readability and maintainability of your code.  For everyone / anyone who might need to read or maintain your code.
- To maximize readability by *other people*, the best strategy is to confirm to an established Java coding standard or style guide.  There are different standards / guides, but (fortunately) they are all pretty much in agreement.
- If the standard doesn't say anything, then use your own judgment about what you think will make the code more readable / maintainable.
- Even the standards are not right all of the time.  They need to simplify things a bit so that their readers can understand them

Ultimately, it is *your call*, though if your code deviates *egregiously* (e.g. messed up indentation, bad identifiers, etc) people will tell you about it.

References

- The current draft of then OpenJDK Style Guidelines are here: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alundblad/styleguide